# Returning a null date value from textbox

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with a returning null text value causing the error, "System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types." I am pulling data from a ListBox in WPF and returning data in ListBoxes, which can be edited and saved. The ShippedDate needs to accept Null values but whenever I try to select a row with no value it crashes.

This is what I have for code currently. The else section works exactly how I want but I am lost on how to handle the null. I appreciate any advice.

```
DateTime OrderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["OrderDate"]);
DateTime RequiredDate = Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["RequiredDate"]);
orderID.Text = OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["OrderID"].ToString();
customerID.Text = OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();
orderDate.Text = OrderDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
requiredDate.Text = RequiredDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");

if (shippedDate.Text == null)
{
    shippedDate.Text = "";
}
else
{
    DateTime ShippedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["ShippedDate"]);
    shippedDate.Text = ShippedDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
}
```

Comment: I have tried to add an answer, but I am slightly confused on your intend. At first it looks like you want to take the some user input via `shippedDate.Text`, but later it seems that you want to insert something in the text box. Could you clarify what the text box is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **System.InvalidCastException** was generated from this part of your code

`Convert.ToDateTime(OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["ShippedDate"]);`

You need to check `OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["ShippedDate"]` against `DBNull`, if it is, don't call `Convert.ToDateTime` with it, for your code, change:

`if (shippedDate.Text == null)`

To:

`if (OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["ShippedDate"] == DBNull)`

Try it.

Comment: I have been trying so many variations of this. I managed to make if work by setting the if statement to: if (OrderDataTable.Rows[0]["ShippedDate"] == DBNull.Value). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is, that it would be easier to use a [DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=netframework-4.8) as this would eliminate most formatting issues. However, it does not affect your null issue.

Regarding your null issue, I don't see any reason to change the `TextBox` text, neither in the `if`, nor in the `else` part. Instead I would do something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(shippedDate.Text) == false)
{
    // Be careful with the naming, you don't want it to be confused with the TextBox
    DateTime sd;
    bool didParse = DateTime.TryParse(shippedDate.Text, out sd);

    if (didParse) 
    {
        // Do stuff with the date (sd)
    }
    else 
    {
        // Maybe show a warning/error
        shippedDate.Text = null;
    }
}
```

Again, it would be simpler with a DatePicker...